# What do all solid amber lights mean on a Cisco 3750 switch?

Tags: cisco, switch

Suddenly, no port lights light up any more. The only lights coming on are the status LEDs on the left of the switch, all are solid amber. Is it dead? Have tried a new power cable. Same happens even if all patch cables are removed.

Comment: When you connect to the console and watch it boot, what do you see?

Comment: In a console I get no output at all. Just solid amber lights.

Comment: She's dead, Jim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news.

It's failing its boot-time diagnostic in a very bad way, which means it is dead.

I hope for your sake it's still under warranty. Else its going to cost money.